# FSharp.Core cannot be found in Xamarin Studio

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin-studio

I have a basic f# project created with Xamarin Studio but it claims it cannot find FSharp.Core.

[image: build error]

However the F# REPL with the IDE works fine so I am assuming that I have f# under mono installed.

Comment: do you know where can we get the path of those dll ?

Comment: To new readers - this is a very old bug, and recent versions of Visual Studio for Mac (certainly anything released in 2017 or later) don't have the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Don Syme via twitter, this error is just cosmetic and the project should build anyway. There is also a bug tracking this

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/30

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/33

I think you need to build the variant FSharp.Core to make this work.

---

EDIT: FWIW, I just tried Xamarin Studio with F# on Win7 and this works just fine.  I can tell by the screenshot that you're working with Mac OS X so whatever the issue is, it seems to be specific to that OS.  It may be worth your while to contact Xamarin and see if they've got any ideas.

By the way, for sake of insuring you can test the same thing on Mac OS X, I just created an F# Console App, built it and ran it without any modification. Hope that might help.

Comment: When you say "this works just fine", are you referring to rebuilding the variant FSharp.Core?

Comment: Sorry no--I meant I was able to get the basic F# project opened without it giving me an error about Fsharp.Core

Comment: Any other information about the project you created?  When I do the same thing (Windows, Xamarin Studio, create Android F# project), I get the error from the original question, and the project won't build

Comment: @JamesMoore -- the original question wasn't asking about Android. However, I do have an issue when I try to create an Android app.  But take a look at this: http://fsharp.org/use/android/ and make sure you're doing everything it specifies. You may need to reinstall everything to get it working--that's my next step but just haven't gotten round to trying it.

Comment: If you're building for Android on windows, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fsharp-opensource/c5OGNrAEEc4/LtH_wufVTw0J - you also might need to install the F# 2.0 runtime package (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13450)

Comment: @JamesMoore thanks for following up on this--I get exactly that same error about the F# 2.0 binding but only on Windows 7--not on my Mac. Thanks a bunch for following up on this.